# Sinatra gives "Connection reset by peer" error when requesting Apple UK rss feed

Tags: xml, rss, sinatra, net-http

This is the code I am using to get the xml data from Apple's UK Top 10 rss feed:

```
xml = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('http://ax.itunes.apple.com/WebObjects/MZStoreServices.woa/ws/RSS/topsongs/limit=10/xml')).body
```

Sinatra returns `Errno::ECONNRESET at / - Connection reset by peer`.
The RSS url I used for this was generated from the Apple RSS generator [here](http://itunes.apple.com/rss). The error occurs with other countries' rss feeds but does NOT occur with the default feed (US) found [here](http://www.apple.com/rss/). The backtrace is below:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb in read_nonblock
        @rbuf << @io.read_nonblock(BUFSIZE)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb in rbuf_fill
        @rbuf << @io.read_nonblock(BUFSIZE)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb in readuntil
          rbuf_fill
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb in readline
      readuntil("\n").chop
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb in read_status_line
        str = sock.readline
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb in read_new
        httpv, code, msg = read_status_line(sock)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb in block in transport_request
          res = HTTPResponse.read_new(@socket)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb in catch
      res = catch(:response) {
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb in transport_request
      res = catch(:response) {
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb in request
      res = transport_request(req, &block)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb in request_get
      request(Get.new(path, initheader), &block)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb in block in get_response
          return http.request_get(uri.request_uri, &block)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb in start
          return yield(self)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb in get_response
        new(uri.hostname, uri.port).start {|http|
/home/sinatra/little.rb in block in <top (required)>
    xml = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse('https://itunes.apple.com/gb/rss/topsongs/limit=5/xml')).body
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb in service
      si.service(req, res)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb in run
          server.service(req, res)
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb in block in start_thread
          block ? block.call(sock) : run(sock)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this myself. Turns out I was using the wrong Net:HTTP command. Should have been `Net::HTTP.get('itunes.apple.com','/gb/rss/topsongs/limit=10/xml')`